# Meaning "angry and violent very easily"

Tags: word-meaning

**She became angry and violent very easily.**
I think >angry and violent very easily means

**angry and violent most of the time**.

Please answer whether  my opinion is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No. The statement simply means, she became angry effortlessly, meaning to say , even some small/trivial thing was enough to arouse violence and anger in her. Also it records something which happened in the past, and only in that one particular occurrence.

Google defines easily as:
"**without difficulty or effort**.", To suit your context.

If the statement rather said, "She **becomes** angry and violet easily, then your interpretation of often would have suited, since it implies habitual behavior.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

she : pronoun; subject
became : verb, copular, present tense, indicative mode, indefinite aspect
angry and violent : coordinate adjectives; subject complement
very easily : adverb phrase; modifies "became"

There is no grammatical difference between

> She became angry and violent very easily.

and

> She very easily became angry and violent.

Adverbs and their phrases can modify the verbs that they follow, but they do not modify adjectives from that position.   If "very easily" were meant to modify "angry and violent", the word order would have to be:

> She became very easily angry and violent.

You can *infer* that she often became angry and violent, but the original sentence does not make that statement.   The grammatical aspect is indefinite.   Without further context, we cannot determine how often this state existed.   It could have been a habitual reaction, or it could have been a singular occurrence.

In any case, "angry and violent very easily" is not a coherent phrase.   Those are two separate phrases with two separate relationships to the clause in which they occur.   "Angry and violent" is an indirect modifier of the subject, and "very easily" is a direct modifier of the verb.